# Uncoutable positive summation leads to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading Amir Dembo's note on probability theory, and on page 9 he said that:

> When $\Omega$ is uncontable, if we take $p_{\omega} = P({\{\omega\}}) > 0$ for uncountable many values of $\omega \in \Omega$, then we shall end up with $P(\Omega)=\infty$

I don't know how to derive it. Though in real analysis we know that uncountable positive summation leads to infinity, however, in probality space it only has property about countable summation.

Comment: In analysis an uncountable sum of *positive* terms will give infinity. But this is not so if one only requires the summed terms to be each non-negative. e.g. make them all $0.$

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for your advice, and I have edited the original description

Comment: Perhaps this is simply saying that there cannot be uncountably many outcomes (elements) in the samples space with positive probability, since as you note, the total probability of the sample space should be $1$.

Comment: Hint: show that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that there are infinitely many $\omega\in\Omega$ with $P(\{\omega\}>\frac1n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$S_n:= \left\{ \omega \in \Omega:P(\omega)\in \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac1n\right] \right\}$$ then we know that $S_i \cap S_j = \emptyset,\;i\neq j$ and

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty S_i=\Omega$$

If $\exists n:|S_n| = \infty$ then we are done and $P(\Omega)=\infty$.

Let's assume $|S_n|<\infty,\forall n$ then each $S_n$ is finite, and hence countable. Since $\Omega$ can be expressed as a countable union of $S_n$, we can [show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#cite_note-31)(using [axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice)) that $\Omega$ is also countable, contradicting the assumption that $\Omega$ is uncountable.

Comment: I don't understand your final "therefore" since this is the "even if not" case. There can be many empty $S_i$ keeping the sum finite in this case. The point is that the uncountability of $\Omega$ forces an (uncountably) infinite $|S_n|$ to make the sum infinite (insofar as you can speak of a sum with uncountable infinity) so this case does not occur.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis — ah, yes — I should show why this is a contradiction- thanks!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis -- thanks for the comments -- I've revised to show the contradiction.

Comment: @Bey Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @UESTCfresh happy to help!